# How to trigger change event at initial loading?

Tags: angular

Initially i want to push all the menus into an array with a status of 0 using an initial event trigger,and then make it 1 if it is checked otherwise 0 itself.Is it possible to do an event change when the ngFor loading initially?

```
**app.html**

   <div *ngFor="let menu of menus" class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox"   (change)="updateChecked(menu,$event)"> 
         {{menu.name}}
        </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: not able to understand what do you want to do? Can you give more details

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attach your `menu.status` to `[(ngModel)]` then angular does the job for you, all you need to is provide an array with initial status value for checkbox whether it is `1 or 0`, `ngModel` will change the status value according to checkbox value, internally javascript treats `1 and 0` as `true or false` when you toggle the checkbox, so `menu.status` will be `true or false` in output, below is the working snippet

```
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let menu of menus; let i = index">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="menu.status" (change)="updateChecked(menu, $event)" class="" />{{menu.name}}
          </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

in your typescript file

```
export class AppComponent{
    menus: any[];
    constructor() {
        this.menus = [
            {
                name: 'home',
                status: 0   
            },
            {
                name: 'about',
                status: 1
            }
        ]
    }

    updateChecked(menu, event) {
        console.log(this.menus); // inspect menu, menus and event here
    }
}
```